# c# async task cancellation

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, cancellationtokensource

I have some problems getting a grasp on tasks and cancellation tokens. I've made a program that looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    CancellationTokenSource token = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Stopwatch stop = new Stopwatch();
    stop.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myLongTask(token.Token, (i + 1) * 1000));
    }
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.SpinWait(1000);
        if (stop.ElapsedMilliseconds > 3000)
        {
            token.Cancel();
        }
    }
}

public static void myLongTask(CancellationToken token, int time)
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
        return;
    }
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Console.WriteLine($"Task {time / 1000} started");
    while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < time)
        Thread.SpinWait(1000);
    Console.WriteLine($"Task {time / 1000} ended");

}
```

I am running 5 tasks simultaneously (although when I don't include `Thread.Sleep()` the `for` loop seems to run before tasks are even started?). None of the tasks get ever cancelled when I run the program. Also what is bugging me is...what task am I really cancelling when calling `token.Cancel()`? How can I choose which of the 5 tasks will I kill? I can define each task by it's variable, but I can't access its `CancellationRequested` property since it is triggered with `CancellationToken`. Would I need 5 different tokens then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> None of the tasks get ever cancelled when I run the program.

That's because you're only ever checking the cancellation token at the *start* of the task. Once it's got past that first `token.IsCancellationRequested` check, cancelling the token does nothing. If you move your check into your loop, like this:

```
while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < time)
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
        return;
    }
    Thread.SpinWait(1000);
}
```

... then you'll see the tasks react appropriately.

> Also what is bugging me is...what task am I really cancelling when calling `token.Cancel()`?

You're not cancelling a task - you're cancelling the cancellation token. Any task that *observes* that cancellation token will be cancelled (or complete, or whatever action it takes) but there's no direct correlation between a task and a token.

When we talk about "cancelling a task" we really mean "cancelling a token which we believe the task is observing".

Comment: But if I have 5 different tasks and only one `token.Cancel()`...then it cancels all 5 obviously? If I want to kill a specific task, would I need a token list?

Comment: @Norgul: Yes, you would. Or at least, you'd need 5 different tokens and *some* way of knowing which one is being observed by the task you want to stop.